# Issue with globally visible service in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am tying to make service, which would be visible without importing in component.

My bootstrap function:

```
export function main(initialHmrState?: any): Promise<any> {
  console.log(APP_PROVIDERS);
  return bootstrap(App, [
    ...PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    ...APP_PROVIDERS
  ])
  .then(decorateComponentRef)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

App providers definition:

```
export * from './app.component';
export * from './user.state';
export * from './app.service';

import { UserState } from './user.state';
import { AppState } from './app.service';

// Application wide providers
export const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  UserState,
  AppState
];
```

And i can not call it in components constructor

```
 constructor( private userState: UserState ) {}
```

How i can fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either by importing it or by using a string token or [`OpaqueToken`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html) and `@Inject()

```
export const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  {provide: 'UserState', useClass: UserState},
  AppState
];
```

```
constructor(@Inject('UserState') private userState: any ) {}
```

Comment: I have error  in console when I using it in my component: 

/home/maksym/untill/trunk/unTill.Modern/Code/App/src/app/backoffice/backoffice.component.ts:13:53 
    Cannot find name 'UserState'.

Comment: Sorry, I replaced `UserState` with `any` at the wrong place. I updated my answer. You still need to import `UserState` where you provide it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts:

- Defining the provider names using types
- Using the types for injection

In both cases, you need to import corresponding types. Otherwise, they won't be resolved...

Note that it's not mandatory to use types for dependency injection. You could eventually use `OpaqueToken`s:

```
export const SOME_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('sometoken');
let provider = { provide: token, useClass: UserState };
```

and use it:

```
 constructor( @Inject(SOME_TOKEN) private userState: UserState ) {}
```

But in this case, you also need to import the opaque token...